# Programing in Python

Tags: python, string

I need help with python. How can I separate combine word into two words. At the first we don't know what kind of words could be? so we must enter a string at the input (v="") and then that word must be separate. For example we have "AMnidcrheaal" and in output will be "Andrea" and "Michal".

Comment: `"AMnidcrheaal"[::2]` -> "Andrea". `"AMnidcrheaal"[1::2]` -> "Michal".

Comment: Please take the [tour] and read [ask]. At this point you would be far better served by a [good tutorial](https://sopython.com/wiki/What_tutorial_should_I_read%3F).

Answer (score -1, accepted):

According to the output you gave, you want to separate odd and even indices words which can be done as follows

```
v="AMnidcrheaal"
even=""
odd=""
for i in range(len(v)):
    if i%2==0:
        even+=v[i]
    else:
        odd+=v[i]

print(odd)
print(even)
```

Comment: And if I don't know what word to be? so s=input("Write word:"), v=""

Comment: @Adrien Why do you want to set `s` as the return value you got from input? `s` isn't used anywhere in the answers code. And why do you set `v` to an empty string if this should be the string you want to work with?

Comment: That code wich Om Khade wrote is good, the principle is the same what i need, but i need little different. I don't know what word it is in that v. That's mean it could be hole bunch of words and no only "AMnidfrheaal". I need that v will be unknown.

Comment: @Matthias And because I add s=input("Write word"), print(s) and v="" will be the word what i wrote previously.

Comment: @Adrien In your question you wrote "we must enter a string at the input". I assume that this string is the _word_  you want to split. So why can't you use `v = input()`?